# angularjs ng-options select as custom object from the options array

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I am trying to fetch 2 different ids from ng-options object list and map the same into select model on user select. The model is mapped properly but the value is not shown on select box.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Z3ohLie4vpTvXhUiLfl6?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="angularjs-starter">

      <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Custom Plunker</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="app.js"></script>
      </head>

      <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <h1>Select something</h1>
        <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="{'id':item.id,'anotherid':item.anotherId} as item.name for item in items"></select>
        <h3>The selected item:</h3>
        <pre>{{selectedItem | json}}</pre>
      </body>

    </html>
```

The Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    { id: 1, name: 'foo', anotherId: 11 },
    { id: 2, name: 'bar', anotherId: 22 },
    { id: 3, name: 'blah', anotherId: 33 }];
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using a very old version of Angular. If you can use a fairly recent version, the answer is using the `track by` clause of `ng-options`:

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem"
  ng-options="{'id':item.id,'anotherid':item.anotherId} as item.name for item in items track by item.id"></select>
```

Forked plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/0SwHfYVuYd5iIA9P4mpU?p=preview

Comment: I really don't understand why simple select is so complicated. Anyways +1 for right answer but I would try to find out more simple solution :)

Comment: I agree that the comprehension stuff in selects is overly complicated and underly explained.